# Validation rule to test if a field contains only digits

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I am trying to set a validation rule to check if a field contains only digits

Tried this condition :  `!ISNUMBER(myfield__c)`

But the user can type `123.123`

How to check that each char of the field content is a digit ?

Comment: This seems like it would only be necessary on text fields that you're using to capture numeric input on. Is there a particular reason why you're not using a `Number` field here? That would largely (if not completely) remove the need for a validation rule in the first place.

Comment: @DerekF by using a number type field, if the user input ``00001``, SF will display it as ``1`` , in our case each digit is important ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by using the `REGEX` function

```
!REGEX(myfield__c,"[0-9]*")
```

Comment: You should go ahead an accept your own answer @benaham. (I won't repeat the "two problems" joke)

Comment: @JohnThompson yep in two days, cause there is a validation rule implemented on StackExchange that prevent me from doing it right away :D

Comment: What about the digit `0`?