# Flow screen component - Input number field as zipcode to limit 5 number max

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

Hello I'm trying to add Number type input field in flow screen component as Zipcode.
I would like to set it to max 5 number long.

I have added input validation formula to 
`Len(Zip)<6`

but when i save flow i get error message

> Zip (Screen Component) - The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect
>   parameter type for function 'Len()'. Expected Text, received Number

can anyone help me here?

Comment: You just need to change the field: Zip's datatype to Text, instead of Number.

Comment: Hi @ArnoldJr. I could certainly do that, but then I need validation for number only, as text field would allow alphabets too.

Comment: In that validation, you could have condition to make sure you have only numbers entered for the field: Zip. Something like this: `NOT(ISNUMBER(Zip))`. I haven't tested this, but you could also try from this solution: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177833/validation-rule-to-test-if-a-field-contains-only-digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I have created Text field for Zipcode with validation OR `(ISNUMBER(ZIPCODE) && (LEN(ZIPCODE) < 6))` and it worked fine.

Comment: you need to consider user entering a value like `2` -- do you assume this is zip code `00002` or an error?

Comment: I eventually used `REGEX({!Zip},"\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?")`